# How to melt multiple index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I have the data frame, with multiple index, but i want to melt preserving its index.

This is what i have:

-Summarized DF:

```
Attributes  Adj Close|Close 
Symbols     AALR3.SA | ABCB4.SA 
Date                                                
2019-12-09| 17.862261|17.999647
2019-12-10| 17.852343|18.240801
2019-12-11| 18.001112|18.298676
```

-Picture:
[image]

-The code that i've made to get this df:

```
Brazilian_stock_list1 = ['AALR3.SA','ABCB4.SA']

brazilian_stocks1 = pdr.get_data_yahoo(Brazilian_stock_list1, start=start_date, end=end_date)

razilian_stocks1.head()
```

-What i've tried, but it deleted index "Date":

```
pd.melt(brazilian_stocks1, value_vars=teste.columns.tolist())
```

[image]

-And finally, this is what i need:

```
date        Attributes  Symbols      value
2019-12-09  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    17.862.261
2019-12-10  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    17.852.343
2019-12-11  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    18.001.112
2019-12-12  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    18.229.223
```

Thanks in advance for any help you provide me.

Comment: I think you can provide an `id_vars` parameter, that accepts a list, containing all the index values you're going to perform the melt on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `stack` then `reset_index`:

```
df.stack(level=(0,1)).reset_index(name='value')
```

Output:

```
         Date  Attribute   Symbols      value
0  2019-12-09  Adj Close  AALR3.SA  17.862261
1  2019-12-09      Close  ABCB4.SA  17.999647
2  2019-12-10  Adj Close  AALR3.SA  17.852343
3  2019-12-10      Close  ABCB4.SA  18.240801
4  2019-12-11  Adj Close  AALR3.SA  18.001112
5  2019-12-11      Close  ABCB4.SA  18.298676
```